# Please Tell Me What is Wrong in My Code?!! Need to convert a 2D array into a side by side 1D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 2}};
    System.out.println(line(arr));
}

public static int[] line(int[][] arr) {
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            size++;
        }
    }
    int[] array = new int[size];
    int place = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            array[place] = arr[i][j];
            place++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

The eror I'm getting is

----jGRASP exec: java Problem
[I@15db9742

----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: please start by formatting your code in a way that is readable. Also, I don't see an error in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object has a `toString()` method, and the default method is to display the object's class name representation, then "@" followed by its `hashcode`. So what you're seeing is the default `toString()` representation of an `int array`. To print the data in the array, you can use

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(line(arr)));
```

Or you can loop through the array with a for loop like this

```
int [] res = line(arr);
for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++){
System.out.println(res[i]);
}
```

Comment: how would I use the for loop? 
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[][] arr = {{2,3,4},{3,4,5,2}};
      line(arr);
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
      }
   }

this doesn't work either.

Comment: @InNeedOfHelp Updated my answer for `for loop` also

Comment: Thank you so much.. extremely grateful

Comment: @InNeedOfHelp Glad I helped

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TEst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = { { 2, 3, 4 }, { 3, 4, 5, 2 } };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line(arr)));
    }

    public static int[] line(int[][] arr) {
        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                size++;
            }
        }
        int[] array = new int[size];
        int place = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                array[place] = arr[i][j];
                place++;
            }
        }
        return array;`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. you guys are so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see it is working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 2}};
    int[] i = line(arr);
    Arrays.stream(i).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + ""));
}

public static int[] line(int[][] arr) {
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            size++;
        }
    }
    int[] array = new int[size];
    int place = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            array[place] = arr[i][j];
            place++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

the only thing is when you are writing out your result you get the object reference not the array in plain text.

```
2
3
4
3
4
5
2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: thank you for your response. yes I realized that I hadn't initialized a new 1D array in the main method as well which just caused massive confusion.